# Ok to accept self-signed certificate if I control both server and client?

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have an app going into production.  It has a java client and a java server, both of which are always the same, and under my team's control.  We are using https.

Is it OK in this situation to issue a self-signed certificate and accept it on the client?  Is there any risk there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTTPS is to protect the connection between server and client and you don't control this connection fully just by controlling both server and client. If you accept  any self-signed certificate just because you control server and client then you would also accept a certificate from a man in the middle, i.e. this would be insecure.

What you can do is to hard code the expected certificate in the client, i.e. certificate pinning. This way you only accept this specific certificate and a man in the middle attack using another certificate is not possible.